# How to make $where and RegExp.prototype.test() to work

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this 2 commands in mongodb:

```
1.- db.tag.find({$where:"'star wars episode VII'.search(this.name) >= 0"})
2.- db.tag.find({$where: "/this.name/.test('star wars episode VII')"})
```

and the collection below:

```
db.tag.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f7107c55b2acc61000bc8"), "name" : "star" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f710fc55b2acc61000bc9"), "name" : "star wars" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f7117c55b2acc61000bca"), "name" : "spider" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("537087d16ac5b5f6f58f0b1b"), "name" : "starting" }
```

**Question:**

Why option 1 is returning the data I need but option 2 is not giving any output? what is the problem with option 2?

e.g.

```
db.tag.find({$where:"'star wars episode VII'.search(this.name) >= 0"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f7107c55b2acc61000bc8"), "name" : "star" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f710fc55b2acc61000bc9"), "name" : "star wars" }
```

thank you very much

**SOLUTION:** by Neil Lunn

```
2.- db.tag.find(function(){ var patt = new RegExp(this.name); return patt.test("star wars episode VII"); })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your best  litmus test for this is using a JavaScript [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), much like the mongo shell with your basic principle which is:

```js
var string = "star wars episode VII";
/string/.test("star wars episode VII - a new disney");
```

Which of course is just going to return `false`.

The general problem here is that you cannot use a variable within the `/../` syntax of a regular expression and to do so you would actually need to define this as a `RegExp` object like so:

```js
var patt = new RegExp("star wars episode VII");
patt.test("star wars episode VII - a new disney");
```

So the two statements are not actually equal, and therefore one returns `true` while the other form returns false.

It is kind of true ( though equally horrible to the JavaScript execution ) that you do not need this at all, and could simply do a Regex search:

```js
db.tag.find({ "name": /star wars episode VII/ })
```

MongoDB supports that, but it really isn't advised, but either is usage of the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator. See [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your second query, should you not go the other way round ?

```
db.tag.find({$where: "/star wars episode VII/.test(this.name)"})
```

On the other hand, I would suggest these expressions, which will do exactly the same without a $where clause:

```
db.tag.find({ name: /star wars episode VII/ });
```

or

```
db.tag.find({ name: { $regex: {"star wars episode VII"} } );
```

Comment: For the record, it's not actually the "wrong way around", but it simply does not work with a variable in this form, as was actually explained. And funny enough, answered the actual question about "why does the other form not work"